# React elements do not render after state is updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a react/redux app. My problem is that I can not get the page to render the updated redux object. My guess is that I am doing something "illegal" in the reducer.

I have the following container-element, which is a container wrapper for various react elements.:

```js
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/rhythmActions';
import {Meter} from './Meter';

export const RhythmContainer = (props) => {
  console.log("RhythmContainer");
  let rows = [];
  for (let i=0; i < props.rhythm.meters.length; i++) {
     rows.push(<Meter key={i} actions={actions} store={props.store} rhythm={props.rhythm.meters[i]} meterId={i}/>);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      This will be a 4/4 rhythm
      {rows}
    </div>
  );
};

RhythmContainer.propTypes = {
  rhythm: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    rhythm: state.rhythm,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(RhythmContainer);
```

My reducer is the following:

```js
// Actions to add: ADD_POINTS, EDIT_SCORE, START_TIME, STOP_TIME,
import {TOGGLE_NOTE_VALUE} from '../constants/actionTypes';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function rhythmReducer(state = initialState.rhythm, action) {
  let newState = objectAssign({}, state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_NOTE_VALUE:
        let meter = newState.meters[action.meterId][action.voice].map((note, index) => {
            if (index == action.noteId) {
                console.log(note.value);
                 return Object.assign({}, note,
                    { duration: note.duration, value: !note.value})
            }
            return note
        });
        let meters = state.meters.map(value => Object.assign({}, value));
        meters[action.meterId][action.voice] = meter;
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
           meters: meters
        });
    default:
      return newState;
  }
}
```

The object is updated but there is no re-rendering in the page.

The initial object is:

```js
export default {
  rhythm: {
    meters: [
      {
        crash: [
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
      ],
      hihat: [
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
      ],
      ride: [
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
      ],
      htom1: [
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
      ],
      htom2: [
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
      ],
      ltom: [
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
      ],
      snare: [
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
      ],
      bdrum: [
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },{
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: true,
        },
        {
          duration: 16,
          value: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    ],
  }
};
```

Comment: First of all it should be `default: return state;` instead of `default: return newState;`, if no change occurs you should return the same object not a copy. For your initial problem are you sure you dispatch an action with `TOGGLE_NOTE_VALUE` type

Comment: Can you show how your rythm state looks like and what actually are your tryinng to modify

Comment: @oliv37 yes I am  logging to object and it changes

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I updated the description with the object

Comment: it should be `rhythm={props.rhythm}` instead of `rhythm={props.rhythm.meters[i]}`

Comment: @oliv37 why that?

Comment: shouldn't `actions={actions}` be `actions={props.actions}`?

Comment: One possible thing to look at is how you're initializing your store. Maybe you're doing the name mapping there, but if not, you have a naming mismatch: your reducer function is called `rhythmReducer` but your `mapStateToProps` refers to `state.rhythm`.

Comment: @mulleady1 something must be wrong here since it works both with mine and your suggestion.